# Org repeated task doesn't repeat when DONE

Tags: org-mode, todo

Following the documentation, I set to DONE a repeated task with `C-- 1 C-c C-t` but this actually closes the task definitevely.

```
** TODO Things
   DEADLINE: <2016-01-17 Sun +1m>
```

After typing `C-- 1 C-c C-t` :

```
** DONE Things
   DEADLINE: <2016-01-17 Sun +0m>
```

I noticed that the key sequence seems not to be captured like desired :
I type `C--` and emacs prompt `C--` at the bottom of the window, and after typing `1` the keysequence change to `C- kp-1-` so maybe that is the problem.

And if it is, I don't know how to change this behaviour.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html):

> When you mark a DEADLINE or a SCHEDULE with the TODO keyword DONE, it will no longer produce entries in the agenda. The problem with this is, however, that then also the next instance of the repeated entry will not be active. Org mode deals with this in the following way: When you try to mark such an entry DONE (using C-c C-t), it will shift the base date of the repeating timestamp by the repeater interval, and immediately set the entry state back to TODO

In other words, `DONE` for a repeating task means that it should not repeat any more because it is "DONE". If it is truly a repeating task, marking it as `DONE` like normal with `C-c C-t` will keep the state as `TODO`, but shift the timestamp ahead to the next repetition, so that you know when to do it again.

So if you want to mark the current instance of a repeating task as `DONE`, do it as you would any other task. If you are done with it for good, i.e., you want to "close the task definitively", then you can use `C-- 1 C-c C-t`, or delete or archive the task.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I get a little confused with th `C-- 1` prefix. English is not my native language ! ^^

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto no problem! That prefix was confusing for me too, and the explanation of what that key combination does is too brief and not so clear in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

according this note http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html ,org
repeat task use  scheduled date, usually with a .+ style repeat interval.

so your task should be:

```
** TODO Things
    SCHEDULED: <2016-01-17 Sun .+1m>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE:    habit
    :END:
```