# Change keyword of Org item without triggering repeat

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a `BLOCKED` keyword that I want to be able to temporarily set on repeating tasks in Org mode. However, if I set this up with `(org-todo "BLOCKED")`, this triggers a repeat. I don't want to trigger a repeat, I just want to change the status.

There seems to be some special behavior in `org-mode` where if you run `org-todo` interactively with a prefix argument of `-1`, then this makes the task `TODO` without triggering a repeat. See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19603/org-repeated-task-doesnt-repeat-when-done) for details. I want to be able to do something similar, where I make a task `BLOCKED` without triggering a repeat.

The function `org-cancel-repeater` (which is used for the `C-u -1` behavior) does not seem to help since it just sets the repeater interval to `0` permanently without providing a way to restore it. This seems almost roundabout. I'm not sure why Org was not simply written to change the keyword without affecting the repeater interval. Setting it to zero so that it works implicitly seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Elisp code defines a new command `org-todo-keep-repeater`.
Used interactively it prompts the user for a new TODO state with completion and applies it without modifying the repeater.

The OP [Matthew Piziak](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/594/matthew-piziak) mentioned that `org-cancel-repeater` should save information for restoring the repeater.
That idea is implemented in `org-todo-keep-repeater`.

It works by temporarily augmenting `replace-match` used in `org-cancel-repeater` such that it saves the match string, the beginning position, and end position of the match before replacing it.
With this information the repeater is restored after calling `org-todo`.

```el
(defun org-todo-keep-repeater (todo)
  "Call `org-todo' with TODO keyword but keep repeater."
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Set todo state of current headline to:" org-todo-keywords-1)))
  (let ((my-marker-b (make-marker))
    (my-marker-e (make-marker))
    my-original-repeater)
    (cl-letf* ((old-replace-match (symbol-function 'replace-match))
           ((symbol-function 'replace-match)
        (lambda (&rest args)
          (setq my-original-repeater (match-string 0))
          (set-marker my-marker-b (match-beginning 0))
          (set-marker my-marker-e (match-end 0))
          (apply old-replace-match args))))
      (org-cancel-repeater))
    (if my-original-repeater
    (progn
      (org-todo todo)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char my-marker-b)
        (delete-region my-marker-b my-marker-e)
        (insert my-original-repeater))
      (set-marker my-marker-b nil)
      (set-marker my-marker-e nil))
      (org-todo todo))))
```

Alternatively one could write a new function that works like `org-cancel-repeater` saving the original repeater before canceling it.

Both approaches

1. temporarily modifying the old `org-cancel-repeater`
2. writing an new function working like `org-cancel-repeater`

have advantages and disadvantages.

The first approach works as long as `org-cancel-repeater` uses `replace-match` for the repeater. It follows all other potential future modifications on `org-cancel-repeater`. The second approach would make `org-todo-keep-repeater` more robust against modifications of `org-cancel-repeater` but it would also not follow potential development on `org-cancel-repeater`.